# Fragment activity gets destroyed when entering new activity from fragment and going back

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, back-stack

I have an activity of type FragmentActivity. Inside I have some content using view pager, where each scrollable tab is a fragment:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager      
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".OpenStack" >

    <!--
    This title strip will display the currently visible page title, as well as the page
    titles for adjacent pages.
    -->

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#33b5e5"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Inside the fragment I'm opening a new activity when user taps on the item in the list like this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), InstanceActivity.class);
getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);
```

But when i click back in the InstaceActivity to return to the one with fragments it is destroyed and created again. I have to no idea why that happens. Should I do something special to keep the FragmentActivity in the backstack?

It doesn't even help to save the state with:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("CONNTOKEN", isConnToken);
    outState.putString("NOVAURL", isNovaURL);
}
```

Because in the oncreate event of the FragmentActivity the savedInstanceState is NULL when I press back ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [addToBackStack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack%28java.lang.String%29).  ;)

Comment: From what I understand, that is used when going from fragment to another fragment, but here i'm going from fragment to activity.

Comment: I'm not changing fragments here and I can only use addToBackStack on FragmentTransaction. I tried that anyway, but it didn't change anything.